# Majorana Mass term for $SU(2)_L$ doublets

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, majorana-fermions

Assume we add a colorless and hyperchargeless $SU(2)_L$ fermion doublet to the Standard Model.

$$L=\left(\begin{matrix}L_u\\L_d\end{matrix}\right)$$

Then, considering gauge invariance, the lagrangian should contain a term
$$ML^TCi\sigma_2L$$
where $M$ is some mass scale and $\sigma_2$ is the second Pauli matrix. Under a transformation $U(x)\in SU(2)$ which can be parameterized as
$$U(x)=\exp\left\{\frac{i}{2}\vec{\theta}(x)\cdot\vec{\sigma}\right\}$$
this term transforms as
$$ML^TCi\sigma_2L\longrightarrow ML^TCU^Ti\sigma_2UL=ML^TCi\sigma_2L$$
which is invariant due to
$$\sigma_2\sigma_i\sigma_2 = -\sigma_i\;\;.$$
But, we can decompose this term as
$$ML^TCi\sigma_2L=M\left(L_d^TCL_u - L_u^TCL_d\right)$$
and using
$$L_u^TCL_d=\left(L_u^TCL_d\right)^T\\\qquad\;\;\;\;=-L_d^TC^TL_u\\\qquad\;=L_d^TCL_u$$
where in the first step we take the transpose of a scalar which we can always do, in the second step the minus sign arises from the anti-commuting properties of fermion fields and in the last step the second minus sign comes from $C^T=-C$, this term should vanish. Still I have seen it...

So to my question. Does this term vanish or not?

Comment: what about the last transpose of the C-operator? I think, the transpose should be removed.

Comment: Thank you I forgot to delete it